# Get URL from a HTML text in Android Java

Tags: java, android

```
String htmlText = Html.toHtml((Spanned) editText.getText());
//output of htmlText = "<span style="background-color:#F9F9F9;"><b><a href="someUrl">Some Text</a></b></span>"
```

How can I get the URL link in the `<a>` tag so that I'll have something like

```
String urlStr = "someUrl";
```

Comment: Use an HTML parser, such as JSoup.

Comment: @CommonsWare Please can you show me how to do it, I'm still new to Java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay... I was able to figure it out with the help of the comment from @CommonsWare.

First, I had to add the `JSoup` library to my android project then with this code below

```
String htmlText = Html.toHtml(editText.getText());
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(htmlText, "UTF-8");
Elements element = doc.select("a").first();
String href = element.attr("href");
```